# The new command requires to be run outside of a project, but a project definition was found at

Tags: angular

I get the following error when trying to create a component: `ng n c test`

> error: The new command requires to be run outside of a project, but a project definition was found at he new command requires to be run outside of a project, but a project definition was found at "C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\basics-assignment-2-start\angular.json".

Comment: you have to execute the command in the directory where angular.json file is presnt not outside or inside exactly at angular.json file directory level.

Comment: Given the other args, you probably wanted `ng g`enerate, not `ng n`ew.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the help, that was the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to create a new workspace and new angular application [Check cli commands here](https://angular.io/cli)

`new    n`

> Creates a new workspace and an initial Angular app.

You are already in an angular application so the cli just tells you that you can't do it.

If you are trying to generate a new component (as I think you are, try `ng g c test` in your angular project. Beware that the component will be created relatively to the position you are currently at.